# Capturing text from a TD cell and concatenate variable to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking for some help on how to capture value for a specific TD cell. The challenge i'm faced with is that I cannot modify the TD cell to include classes or modify them as the table content are created dynamically by another system.

I created the fiddle below to give you an idea of what the structure of the table. As i explained above since I cannot directly modify the table structure or add extra classes to make it easier to target the TD cell I want, I am trying to Macgyver my way out of this one.

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

1) Need to capture the Reference number (Always 11 characters long and only contains numbers).

2) Put the captured reference number into a variable.

3) Concatenate the variable to the following url http://test.com/UpdateNotification.asp?OEN= (variable here) &CL=ALL&SU=ALL

4) Replace the Reference number with the URL.

So I am really having problems with the step 1 of this process. I would appreciate some help on this.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/5665/

```
<DIV class="sm_content">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb2">reference numbers</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">name</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Description</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Incident</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb2">20150715110</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Jhonson Doe</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Box of cereal and other stuff</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb2">20150715111</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Bobby Boucher</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">Box of nails and stuff</td>
            <td class="ms-vb2">124</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please make an effort before asking. That said, coders gotta code.

```
$('.sm_content table tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
    var myId = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
    var myUrl = 'http://test.com/UpdateNotification.asp?OEN=' + myId;
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).html('<a href="' + myUrl + '">' + myId + '</a>');
});
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/W4Km8/5667/)**

Or, if you didn't actually want the ID linked, just do this for the last line:

```
$(this).find('td').eq(0).text(myUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code isherwood, this did works for me. However, when there are no entries to display the table outputs a message saying theres nothing to display and makes that a URL. Would you have any idea how to prevent that? Heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/5672/

Comment: The short answer is that you could use a regular expression to detect non-numeric characters and an `if` statement to filter the operation. Please ask a new question if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do it.

```
(function($){
    $('.sm_content tr').slice(1).each(function(){
        var td = $(this).find('td').first();
        var tdContent = td.html();
        td.html('<a href="http://test.com/UpdateNotification.asp?OEN=' + tdContent + '&CL=ALL&SU=ALL" alt="' + tdContent + '">' + tdContent + '</a>');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

Load the entire page into a string.  I've used `phpfilegetcontents` but for an html only page I'd manually copy and paste the page into a text box and use `document.getElementbyid('box').innerHTML` to load the page's contents into a string

Find the first cell: `entirepage.indexOf('td')`

`entirepage.slice(start from location of td plus enough characters to get past the rest of the tag, end 11 characters later)`
that's your reference number
find the nth instance of 'td'
and so on.

no jquery necessary

Comment: While this might theoretically answer the OP's question, it would be helpful to provide an example in code of your solution - as it is, it's hard to understand exactly what you're suggesting.